# MVC iOS - tableview cell

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I'm a bit confused with **MVC** pattern in **Swift/Obj C**.

Should I put UITableViewCell into **View** folder and ViewController to **Controller** folder?

Comment: Yes, the cell is a view and the controller is a controller.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

UITableViewCell file : View

UIViewController file : Controller

Class file which contains your object data : Model

## Personal Opinion

First of all. Let's take a quick look on **MVC** :

Model View Controller or MVC as it is popularly called is made up of the following three parts :

**Model** − Responsible for maintaining data.

**View** − Responsible for displaying the data to the user.

**Controller** − Software Code that controls the interactions between the Model and View.

For a while i was confused about what is the best place for UITableViewCell file ! I have asked my senior, explored blogs and the most important thing was giving my self a minute to think logically and finally i have got the answer.

So my answer is a some kind of sharing knowledge with you and the others from the future.

When you are working with a table view, you have a **UITableViewCell** files, **UIViewController** file and a **class file** which contains your data. Right ?

First things first, u can easily figure out that UIViewController should be in **Controller** folder and the class file which contains your object data should be in **Model** folder.

#### What about UITableViewCell file ?

This file contains the outlets of your cell which are responsible for displaying the data to user. Simple.

Good luck :)